# What are the Schur indices of irreducible representations of $\operatorname{SL}(2,p)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$What are the Schur indices of the irreps of $\SL(2,p)$? ($p$ an odd prime.)

Presumably this is in a book somewhere? Section 6 of the paper ["The computation of some Schur indices" by Feit](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02762888) comes pretty close, and shows that every irrep of $\PSL(2,p)$ has Schur index 1, so this shows that the irreps of $\SL(2,p)$ which are trivial on the center also have Schur index 1. It also shows that the other irreps have Schur index dividing 2, but I'm not quite sure if his results actually determine the Schur indices for all faithful reps.

Answer (score 9):

If $p \equiv 1$ mod $4$ then all faithful irreducibles have Schur index two, and Schur indicator $-1$. If $p \equiv 3$ mod $4$, then most do, but there are two irreducibles of dimension $(p+1)/2$ with Schur index one and Schur indicator $0$. They are swapped by the outer automorphism.

Comment: Can you say a few more words about how one can see this? (or give a reference?)

Comment: I'm sure there must be references. I'm just too familiar with the character tables of these groups. It probably comes from half a century of misspent youth. But a good starting point might be the book of Bonnafé.

Comment: There's also a good article by the late great Jim Humphreys, with the title "Representations of $SL(2,p)$".

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, but shows how this can be calculated from the character table (at least in this case) without using the usual Frobenius-Schur formula $\nu(\chi) = \frac{1}{|G|} \left( \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g^{2}) \right)$, which requires knowing which conjugacy classes contain squares from other classes ( $\nu(\chi)$ denotes, of course, the Frobenius-Schur indicator). It partially addresses the question you asked @DaveBenson
in comments.

If we consider the non-faithful irreducible characters of ${\rm SL}(2,p)$, we find that $\sum_{\chi \in {\rm Irr}({\rm PSL}(2,p))} \nu(\chi)\chi(1)$ is the number of square roots of the identity in $G = {\rm PSL}(2,p)$ which is $1 + [G:C_{G}(t)]$ for any involution $t \in G$, since $G$ has a single conjugacy class of involutions.

On the other hand, the group ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ contains exactly one involution, so we obtain $\sum_{\chi \in {\rm Irr}({\rm SL}(2,p))} \nu(\chi)\chi(1) = 2.$

This tells us that the sum of $\nu(\chi)\chi(1)$, where $\chi$ runs over all faithful irreducible characters of ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ is $1-[G:C_G(t)]$ (where $G$ still denotes ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$ and $t$ is any of the involutions of $G$).

This is not a complete explanation of Dave's answer, but it should make it possible to check from the character table of ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ (in any case, it explains why many of the faithful irreducible characters of ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ must have indicator $-1$).

Comment: Thanks, Geoff! Nice explanation.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned the Brauer-Speiser theorem, which links the Schur index of real-valued irreducible characters with their Frobenius-Schur indicator.